# How to pass a list of types instead of interfaces in java

Tags: java, casting

I have a list of Event (interface) and thats what I want to return in my method

```
public List<Event> getEvents(){ return list;}
```

Inside the class I need to initialize the list.

```
List<EventImpl> list = new ArrayList<EventImpl>();
```

For some reason I thought I could do this:

```
List<Event> list = new ArrayList<EventImpl>();
```

But it appears I can't, So do i need some casting magic in getEvents()?  If so how is that done?

Thanks

Comment: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `getEvents()` to return a `List<Event>`, the easiest way is to create a `List<Event>` in the method in the first place:

```
List<Event> list = new ArrayList<Event>();
```

The fact that `list` will end up consisting only of `EventImpl` instances is irrelevant.

If this is not possible for some reason (for example if the method involves fetching a `List<EventImpl>` from somewhere else), you can convert a `List<EventImpl>` to a `List<Event>` by writing

```
List<Event> copy = new ArrayList<Event>(listOfEventImpl);
```

However you're better off only ever using `List<Event>` and `ArrayList<Event>` in your code, and avoiding `List<EventImpl>` and `ArrayList<EventImpl>`. This adheres to the general good practice that you should refer to interfaces rather than concrete types whenever possible.

(Or you can use wildcards, as others have suggested.)

Answer (score 4):

You should use `List<? extends Event>`. Java has strict rules about type inheritance in generics and the code `List<Event> list = new ArrayList<EventImpl>();` is not valid.

If it were valid then you could have something like `list.add(new SomeOtherEventImpl())`, where `SomeOtherEventImpl` extends/implements `Event` but not `EventImpl`. That would obviously result in an error since `SomeOtherEventImpl` would not fit in a list that requires `EventImpl`.

Comment: Is this syntax ( List<? extends Event> ) saying.  Any object that extends Event?

Comment: Correct. It would be any class that directly or indirectly extends Event.